# Why isn't content showing up in one of the two UICollectionView's in my app that are sharing the same custom UICollectionViewCell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a 2 UICollectionView's.

One is dedicated to a grid style display and the other to a single file display. This is controlled by a UISegmentedControl.

**The grid style collection view was created in interface builder:**

[image]

The other collection view was created programmatically within the viewDidLoad method of the custom class of my default grid style collection views controller.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    [layout setItemSize:CGSizeMake(140, 272)];
    [layout setMinimumLineSpacing:1];
    [layout setMinimumInteritemSpacing:1];
    [layout setSectionInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
    [layout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical];

    _collectionView2 = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame collectionViewLayout:layout];

    [_collectionView2 setDelegate:self];
    [_collectionView2 setDataSource:self];
    [_collectionView2 registerClass:[VAGGarmentCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell2"];
    [_collectionView2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

    [self.view addSubview:_collectionView2];
    [_collectionView2 setHidden:YES];


}
```

I'm using the same custom cell with both these collection views.

Here are my dataSource and delegate methods which both collection views use.

**1:**

```
-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if ([collectionView isEqual:_collectionView]) {
      NSArray *people = [_thisController objects];
      return [people count];
    } else if ([collectionView isEqual:_collectionView2]) {

        NSArray *people = [_thisController objects];
        return [people count];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**2:**

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object
{




    if ([collectionView isEqual:_collectionView2]) {
        NSLog(@"collectionview 2 loaded");
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell2";
        VAGGarmentCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        PFFile *userImageFile = [object valueForKey:@"image"];
        [[cell imageView] setFile: userImageFile];
        [[cell imageView] loadInBackground];
        [[cell title] setText:[object valueForKey:@"title"]];
        [[cell price] setText:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"£%@ GBP", [object valueForKey:@"price"]]];
        return cell;



    } else if ([collectionView isEqual:_collectionView]) {
                NSLog(@"collectionview 1 loaded");
             static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        VAGGarmentCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier: CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

        [[cell activityIndicator] startAnimating];

        PFFile *userImageFile = [object valueForKey:@"image"];
        [[cell imageView] setFile: userImageFile];
        [[cell imageView] loadInBackground];


        [[cell activityIndicator] stopAnimating];

        [[cell title] setText:[object valueForKey:@"title"]];
        [[cell price] setText:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"£%@ GBP", [object valueForKey:@"price"]]];
        return cell;

    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Here is method triggered when the segmented control is tapped:**

```
- (void)displayTypeSegmentSelected
{
    _selectedDisplayTypeIndex = [_displayTypeControl selectedSegmentIndex];

    if (_selectedDisplayTypeIndex == 0) {
        NSLog(@"Single file item view selected");

        [_collectionView setHidden:YES];
        [_collectionView2 setHidden:NO];
        [_collectionView2 reloadData];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Grid style view selected");
        [_collectionView setHidden:NO];
        [_collectionView2 setHidden:YES];
         [_collectionView reloadData];
    }
}
```

I feel everything is done correctly. My main collection view shows up when I tap the grid style side of the segmented control.

**When I tapped the single file segment control option this was the result:**

[image]

As you can see the cells show up but are empty. I'm not quite sure what is going on. If I tap the grid style segment option the main collection view displays fine.

However although the single file collection view shows the correct amount of cells, no content is shown. There should be an image and some text underneath it.

I can't help but think I'm missing a step. Is there some step taken in IB automatically that I haven't done programmatically with my second custom view?

Please note that I haven't yet changed cell size settles to make collection view 2 single file style. I want to first get the content to show up before I move any further.

Help is appreciated

Regards

**Update:**

```
#import "VAGGarmentCell.h"

@implementation VAGGarmentCell


- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code

    }
    return self;
}
```

**and .h for garment cell:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Parse/Parse.h>

@interface VAGGarmentCell : UICollectionViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet PFImageView *imageView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *addFavouriteButton;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *title;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *price;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;
```

Comment: I suspect a difference in cell initialization. Do you mind posting the code of VAGGarmentCell? or at least the parts where you are initializing stuff. Remember that when done in IB, `awakeFromNib` is called. When not, `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:` is called.

Comment: @MatíasR posted the updates. My custom cell only declares properties and that's it.

Comment: There is your problem. When you initialize the cell for _collectionView2, none of the outlets is being wired to the views.  There are two ways to solve it... As @rdelmar said, or by initializing and laying out the views in the cell programmatically in `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is trying to use the cell in _collectionView2 that is defined in your storyboard collection view. Instead of doing that, delete the cell from the storyboard collection view, and make the cell in a xib file. Change the class of that cell to VAGGarmentCell, and hook up any IBOutlets to the VAGGarmentCell class. In viewDidLoad, register the nib (not the class) for both controllers.,

```
[_collectionView2 registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"VAGGarmentCell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell2"];
[self.collectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"VAGGarmentCell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
```

You can use the same reuse identifier or different ones, it doesn't matter as long as the ones you register are the same as the ones you use in celForItemAtIndexPath for their respective controllers.

Comment: I will try this out. Can this same type of thing be achieved with my collection view? So I could create the second collection view in an XIB file instead and this way I can create the custom cell there too?

Comment: @LondonGuy, yes you could create the collection view in a xib, but there's not really any reason to do so. Creating the cell in the xib is enough.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Ended up creating a second cell but used the same principle described in this answer. Works perfectly.